# Multiple files in single request using ng2-file-upload or ngx-uploader

Tags: file-upload, angular6, ng2-file-upload, ngx-uploader

I am using ngx-uploader to implement file upload in my project.
But when I upload multiple files, it seperate the files array to multiple request. 
I have tried to use ng2-file-upload but the same result.

Answer (score 2):

See this thread on GitHub:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/671

I haven't tested it yet but looks promising.